# convert timestamp into Milliseconds

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I am working in the oracle database and I have a timestamp column in which I am supposed to add the current time in it. I am using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for that. this time is added through the trigger function. The CURRENT_TIMESTAMP adds time in date format which is 2020-10-08 12:28:40.842548. but I want it to be added in the format of milliseconds which is 1533680034852. can you please help me which this thing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: NB, 1533680034852 is `2018-08-07 22:13:54.852 UTC` (not `2020-10-08 12:28:40.842548`)

Answer (score 2):

To get `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in milliseconds you can use

```
select (sysdate - to_date('01-01-1970','DD-MM-YYYY')) * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) 
      + to_number(to_char(systimestamp,'FF3')) 
  from dual;
```

Comment: Timestamp is based on `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`! - `SYSDATE` might be UTC time or not.

Comment: This is wrong for Unix time as `SYSDATE` is database local time and does not have the same time as `SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIME ZONE 'UTC'`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a function like this:

```
create or replace function getTimestamp() return number as
   ds interval day(9) to second(3) := systimestamp - TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC';
   res number;
begin
   res := EXTRACT(second FROM ds)
          + 60 * EXTRACT(minute FROM ds)
          + 60 * 60 * EXTRACT(hour FROM ds)
          + 60 * 60 * 24* EXTRACT(day FROM ds);
   return 1000 * res;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query:

```sql
SELECT   EXTRACT( DAY    FROM difference ) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
       + EXTRACT( HOUR   FROM difference ) *      60 * 60 * 1000
       + EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM difference ) *           60 * 1000
       + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM difference ) *                1000
           AS milliseconds_since_epoch
FROM   (
  SELECT ( SYSTIMESTAMP - TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' ) as difference
  FROM   DUAL
);
```

or:

```sql
SELECT ( TRUNC( SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'MI' ) - DATE '1970-01-01' )
       * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
       + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM SYSTIMESTAMP ) * 1000
         AS milliseconds_since_epoch
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | MILLISECONDS_SINCE_EPOCH |
> | -----------------------: |
> |        1602709510024.339 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d924c3ef7022759f579aefd352bea887)*